How to implement text highlighting in pdfjs v2.5.207
How to implement text highlighting in pdfjs v2.5.207?
Configuration:
PDF.js version:v2.5.207
Feature already implemented:
By rendering the pdf to Canvas and can do text copying.
Problem to be solved:
Highlight a specified portion of text.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
